# Android Application Build Error: Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-manifest, build-error

I already build some other applications but in this time, I am facing an unfixable error. Please help me out.
In the error it show "Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs". So, I'm giving my manifest.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.sharpwebtechnologies.photoviewer" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.PhotoViewer"
        tools:targetApi="31" >

        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="false" >
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="preloaded_fonts"
            android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Change this line from `</activity>` to `/>` in your `.MainActivity`.

Comment: In future, it may be better to include the relevant section of said logs in your question.

Comment: @MDev If this is an answer, please add it as an answer so it can be accepted.

Comment: @KieranFoot Thanks for your response but RatnadeepPaul hasn't responded to my answer?

Comment: It doesn't work for me. So, I started the same project again. And now it's not showing the same error. But another error occurs :(
Btw, thank you for your support @MDev

Comment: @RatnadeepPaul can you share your logcat error in your question?